Excel Interpolation - #REF! Error
I need to calculate the resulting "Y" based on an input of 'X'.
The equation I'm using below works as long as the 'X' value doesn't exceed 200%.
How can I edit the formula so that I can correct this issue?
Excel Data & Calculation

Formulas:

F2: =INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1)))+(E2-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1))))*(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1))))/(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E2,A2:A7,1))))
F3: =INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1)))+(E3-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1))))*(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1))))/(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E3,A2:A7,1))))
F4: =INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1)))+(E4-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1))))*(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1))))/(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E4,A2:A7,1))))
F5: =INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1)))+(E5-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1))))*(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($B$2:$B$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1))))/(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1))+1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,(MATCH(E5,A2:A7,1))))


#REF! is due to (MATCH(E2, A2:A7, 1)) + 1 when MATCH(E2, A2:A7, 1)) matches the last cell - so +1 is beyond the range (for INDEX($B$2:$B$7). When you get errors, you could  select portions of the formula and hover over to view the partial result for the selected portion.

Too complicated. Use the TREND function adjusted to show the results of a polynomial regression. See the comment of @MGonet to an answer below.

You want to look outside the range of data, so it's no longer an interpolation, but an extrapolation.
In this case, the easiest way to deal with it is to shorten the range of x data from A2:A7 to A2:A6.
For F2, the following formula will then come out:
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1))+
(E2-INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1)))*
(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1)+1)-
INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1)))/
(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1)+1)-
INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,1)))

This notation can be shortened and simplified in various ways, but I do not know if the choice of this notation is not due to the use of an older version of Excel.
In Excel 2021 or later, you can use a formula like this:
    =LET(xw,E2,data,OFFSET(XLOOKUP(xw,$A$2:$A$6,$A$2:$B$6,,-1,2),,,2),
FORECAST.LINEAR(xw,INDEX(data,,2),INDEX(data,,1)))


From a statistics standpoint interpolations/extrapolations are done with best fit curves. I think excel only has a few formulas that can directly do this (linest and logest). But clicking a couple of options when adding a trendline to a scatter plot can give you the formula which you can then plug into a cell, so based on the highlighted formula in the screenshot one can plug in the formula =-(E2^2*2.4997)+E2*9.8422-6.2991 into F2 and drag down to F5.

Some reservations to what I am showing are 1) only 6 data points (but with such a high R2 it may be acceptable) and 2) extrapolation rule of thumb is to avoid expanding out to more than 10% of the high/low values 3) interpolations imply a smoothness assumption.
EDIT
Thanks for the comments. I should have stated based on my interpretation of the OP's complicated formulas and graph, a polynomial trendline seemed better than a liner trendline. This is borne out based on the high R2 (almost perfect fit) over 6 data points.

=INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7^{1,2}), 1)*E2^2+INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7^{1,2}), 1, 2)*E2+INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7^{1,2}), 1, 3)

If you want to use linear regression, it's better like this:
=TREND($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7^{1,2},E2^{1,2})
You can use the TREND function for forecasts.

@MGonet I think you should post that as an answer, along with an explanation of the advantage of doing it this way.

The question was about interpolation, not regression. Here the OP should say whether he understands the difference and what answer he expects.
